# two different table and same column name,while inserting email id check in both table if exist not insert again

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Two different table and same column name, while inserting email id check in both table, if exist same email id in table, again not inserted in to a table.

Model code

```
function form_insert($data, $data1) {
   if ($data1['categoryvalues'] == 'Seller') {
        $this->db->insert('supplier_registration', $data);
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
    } else {

        $this->db->insert('customer_registration', $data);
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
    }
}
```

controller code

```
function register() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'callback_rolekey_exists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[supplier_registration.email]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobileno', 'Mobile No', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|max_length[15]|min_length[8]|matches[ConfirmPassword]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ConfirmPassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $data['ListMenuLevel1'] = $this->Categories_model->listsector1();
        $data['groups1'] = $this->productdisplay_model->fetchingdata();
        $data['flag2'] = "yes";
        //$data['message']="invalid username or password";
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
        //$data['flag'] = 'yes';
        //$this->load->view('login', $data);
    } else {

        $data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('fname'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('lname'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'mobile_no' => $this->input->post('mobileno'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $data1['categoryvalues'] = $this->input->post('optradio');

        if ($this->Register_model->form_insert($data, $data1)) {
            $data['ListMenuLevel1'] = $this->Categories_model->listsector1();
            $data['groups1'] = $this->productdisplay_model->fetchingdata();
            $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
            $this->load->view('home', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really spend few minutes to write a proper question that is easy to understand. Now you have just written a confusing sentence and dumped your code

Comment: you can add unique index on email field in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no reason that you can't use the is_unique check more than once.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[supplier_registration.email]|is_unique[customer_registration.email]');
```